# Raspberry Pi wake up on GPIO

Tags: raspbian, gpio

How can i make Rpi wakeup using GPIO pin.I mean that can i make Rpi sleep using rtcwake command or something like that and wakeup if a GPIO pin becomes high.Is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i make Rpi sleep using rtcwake

No, because the pi does not have an RTC (real time clock), although you could connect one.

However, that won't do you much good because something else the pi does not have is a sleep state.  It is either on, because the power is attached, or off, because the power is not attached.  It cannot be made to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Pi lacks a sleep/suspend state, the best you can do is halt the system (full shutdown) when work is complete, and send a reset signal on [header P6](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#P6_header) to wake it when needed.

To conserve power, make sure to disable unused peripherals (search for 'power' in the [BCM2835 datasheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf)).

There is at least one commercial product that adds a 'virtual sleep' mode to the Pi, in case you're not interested in building it yourself.

For very low power requirements you may want to migrate to a microcontroller, like an Arduino.